# check if there is a cycle in directed graph CS50 tideman

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50, adjacency-matrix, directed-graph

to check cycle the program goes from first node in the graph to every locked node in the graph-> check if its visited before ,then its a cycle ,,else repeat recursively from the checked next node.
when i test it myself it works but when i use it in tideman election it doesnt.

explanation of the problem : https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/tideman/

The goal in this problem to pick a winner from election using tideman voting algorithm. CS50 ide provides test function **Check50** ,I am trying to fix these errors:
    1.lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
   2.lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle.

is my logic wrong?

```
int graph[nodes_count][nodes_count];
bool check_cycle()
{
    //if a node is visited during checking cycles visited[]=true
    bool visited[nodes_count];
    bool circle = false;
    return gointo(circle, visited, 0);
}
bool gointo(bool &circle, bool visited[], int to)
{
// start trip form one node in the graph check if it have been visited ( Cycle )
    visited[to] = true;
    for (int n = 0; n < nodes_count; n++)
    {
        if (graph[to][n])
        {
            if (visited[n])
            {
                circle = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gointo(visited, n);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return circle;
}
```

my full solution:https://pastebin.com/sbua3EGA
thanks for yours time and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you can provide a short piece of code that demonstrates the problem, rather than 250 lines.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys OK done. i put the whole program because i tried the fucntion with my own locked pairs graph and its works

Comment: That's better, but you still need to explain what the various variables represent: `pairs`, `locked`, `visited`.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys i wil try my best ,if you want full understanding of the problem check the link in the question please.

Comment: Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the graph contains two disconnected subgraphs, then your algorithm may fail. Assume the first subgraph doesn't have cycle and the second one has cycles, but if you started the dfs in the first graph then the dfs will complete and you won't notice the cycle.

Comment: @Deepak-Patankar right ,thank you ..but that won't happen in this situation

Comment: Oh ok, @BreairSabir Your implementation of the cycle detection algorithm looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm would be correct in undirected graph. In directed graphs it is not that obvious.

First of all, starting from node 0 you may not visit all the nodes. Counterexample:
 1 -> 0 -> 2

When you start checking from node 0, you will not visit 1 at all. If 1 also has an edge to a cycle, you will not detect it. That means, you should make a loop for each vertex and if it's not visited yet, run 'gointo' function.

With the change described above you may end up finding cycles when there are not any.

For example:

1 -> 2 -> 3

4 -> 2

If you first do gointo(1), you will mark 1, 2 and 3 as visited. Then when calling gointo(4) you will 'detect a cycle', since 4 has edge to already marked vertex. That's why you need two arrays, one that tells that you've already visited the node, the other one that tells that the node was visited in this specific gointo call.

Code should look like this:

```
int graph[nodes_count][nodes_count];
bool check_cycle()
{
    //if a node is visited during checking cycles visited[]=true
    bool visited[nodes_count];
    bool this_call[nodes_count];
    bool circle = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes_count; ++i)
    {
         if(!visited[i] && gointo(circle, visited, i))
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool gointo(bool &circle, bool visited[], int to)
{
// start trip form one node in the graph check if it have been visited ( Cycle )
    visited[to] = true;
    this_call[to] = true;
    for (int n = 0; n < nodes_count; n++)
    {
        if (graph[to][n])
        {
            if (visited[n] && this_call[n])
            {
                circle = true;
            }
            else if(!visited[n])
            {
                gointo(visited, n);
            }
        }
    }
    this_call[to] = false;
    return circle;
}
```